# Approximating Integral over Sphere

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, approximation

I would like help approximating the surface integral
$$\int_{S^{n-1}_{\ge 0}}\frac{1}{\hat n\cdot p}dS$$
where $\hat n$ is the unit normal to the sphere at the given point, $p\in\mathbb{R}^n$ is a fixed vector with all positive components, and $S^{n-1}_{\ge 0}$ is the portion of the sphere in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with all positive components.

The problem has arisen in the following manner. Suppose that one has a budget dependent on time $v(t)$ in a market of $n$ items each with a positive-price varying over time given by the vector $p(t)=\langle p_1,\dots,p_n\rangle$. One way to consider a "purchasing power" would be the number of ways to purchase different amounts of these items, that is,
$$\text{PP}(t)=\#\{x\in\mathbb{N}^n \; |\; x\cdot p(t)\le v(t)\}$$
To approximate this, we want to "undescretize" it. Assuming both to be evenly distributed, the number of such integer-component $x$ ought to be proportional to the volume of the set when extended to real valued components, that is,
$$\text{PP}(t)\sim |\{x\in\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}^n\; |\; x\cdot p(t)\le v(t)\}|$$
Suppose now that some $x_0$ satisfies $x_0\cdot p(t)\le v(t)$, then considering all vectors in the direction of $x_0$ that also satisfy the inequality we get a line of length $v(t)/x_0\cdot p(t)$. Thus this volume can be well approximated by integrating the lengths of these lines over all possible directions resulting in
$$\text{PP}(t)\sim v(t)\int_{S^{n-1}_{\ge 0}}\frac{1}{\hat n\cdot p}dS$$
The best I could do to approximate this integral was to consider the following,
$$\int_{S^{n-1}_{\ge 0}}\frac{1}{\hat n\cdot p}dS=\frac{1}{\|p\|}\int_{S^{n-1}_{\ge 0}}\frac{1}{\cos\theta}dS$$
where $\theta$ is the angle between $p$ and the current normal $\hat n$. To approximate this I decided to integrate with respect to $\theta$ sweeping outwards on the sphere by the angle from $p$ starting at $p$ where $\theta = 0$. If we let $\theta_0=\min\{\angle(e_1,p),\dots, \angle(e_n,p)\}$ clearly we can sweep outwards to $\theta_0$ without leaving the bounds of $S^{n-1}_{\ge 0}$, however moving past this angle from $p$ will leave these bounds. However, I figure that (possibly incorrectly) that the contribution at a given angle will be roughly proportional to the fraction of the axes within that angle to $p$. That is
$$\frac{1}{\|p\|}\int_{S^{n-1}_{\ge 0}}\frac{1}{\cos\theta}dS\sim \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\#\{e_i \; |\; \angle(e_i, p)\le \theta\}}{n}\cdot \frac{1}{\cos \theta}\cdot \frac{2 \pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma(n/2)}\theta^{n-1}d\theta$$
where the upper bound of $\pi/2$ was relatively arbitrary simply because $\#\{e_i \; |\; \angle(e_i, p)\le \theta\}$ is guaranteed to be zero for $\theta$ any larger. Since we know that $\angle(e_i,p)=\arccos(p_i/\|p\|)$ we can simplify this integral to
$$\begin{aligned}
&\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\#\{e_i \; |\; \angle(e_i, p)\le \theta\}}{n}\cdot \frac{1}{\cos \theta}\cdot \frac{2 \pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma(n/2)}\theta^{n-1}d\theta \\
=&\frac{2\pi^{n/2}}{n\Gamma(n/2)}\sum_{i=1}^n\int_{0}^{\arccos(p_i/\|p\|)}\theta^{n-1}\sec\theta \;d\theta
\end{aligned}$$
All in all I thus feel as if (although I lack a fully formal proof) that
$$\text{PP}(t)\sim \frac{v(t)}{\|p(t)\|}\cdot\frac{2\pi^{n/2}}{n\Gamma(n/2)}\sum_{i=1}^n\int_{0}^{\arccos(p_i/\|p\|)}\theta^{n-1}\sec\theta \;d\theta$$
but this is the best I can do. I can't seems to simplify or approximate that final integral either. I could possibly use a series expansion of $\sec(x)$ and term-wise integrate.

Comment: Suppose $n=2$ and $p=(1,-1).$ Then you are integrating

$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{\cos t -\sin t}\, dt.$$

That has a problem at $t=\pi/4.$ What sense does the integral make in this case?

Comment: My bad, $p$ should have all positive components in this problem since it represents prices. If any were $\le 0$ then $\text{PP}$ would be infinite as per definition, as well as have problems in all the approximations.

Comment: By $v(t)/x_0\cdot p(t)$ you mean $v(t)/(x_0\cdot p(t))$?

Comment: Two things: a) You don't get the volume of $\{x\in\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}^n\; |\; x\cdot p(t)\le v(t)\}$ by integrating the lengths of these lines. You're not taking into account that the line contributes more to the volume the further away from the origin it is. E.g. in three dimensions, you should be integrating the volumes of cones along these lines. The correct integrand would be proportional to $r^n$, not to $r$. b) Why are you integrating this in spherical coordinates instead of Cartesian coordinates? The integral is straightforward in Cartesian coordinates.

Comment: @joriki Ah you're right. How is it easy in Cartesian coordinates though? Is something like $$\int_{0}^{v/p_1}\int_0^{(v-p_1x_1)/p_2}\dots\int_0^{(v-p_1x_1-\dots-p_{n-1}x_{n-1})/p_n}dx_n\dots dx_1$$ what you had in mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the volume of the set $\{x\in\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}^n\; |\; x\cdot p\le v\}$. This is the volume of $\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}^n$ defined by the coordinate planes and the plane $x\cdot p=v$. This is a simplex with coordinate axis intercepts $x_i=v/p_i$. Thus it has the volume $1/n!$ of the unit simplex scaled by $\prod_iv/p_i$.

Comment: This is an incredibly simpler approach. Thanks!